# What Mac Pro Would I need to run 2 Virtual OSs simultaneously

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

If I were to run Ubuntu, W7 AND Mac OS X via VirtualBox (or Parallels) on a Mac Pro, what would I need to make them run perfectly fine in seamless mode?

And I mean, no hiccups, no laggy windows, etc.

Comment: You could buy [64 Raspberry Pi's](http://www.southampton.ac.uk/mediacentre/features/raspberry_pi_supercomputer.shtml) :P

Answer (score 2):

Get the biggest CPU and the most Memory you can. Discrete graphics would help too.

There will always come a time where high-resouce applications running in any other OSes will result in lag, hiccups, or slowness. It is unreasonable to expect otherwise.

But by getting the beefiest hardware you can afford, you will minimize the possible conditions under which that would occur.

Comment: Yeah, I assumed that id still get hiccups, I just meant normal condition stuff. For example, on my new Mac Mini unibody I run W7 and for the most part its fine, but moving a window around fast makes the window lag and go super slow. I mean stuff like that and be able to do Aero or Beryl effects as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking at buying a new Mac Pro soon, don't. The current line is outdated and will probably be renewed either at WWDC or when Intel's Ivy-bridge is announced later in the summer.

NEVER buy RAM from apple. They charge outrageous prices for it - installing the RAM yourself after purchasing from newegg will literally save you hundreds of dollars.

Finally, you don't actually need a lot of computing power to run virtual machines. On a quad core CPU and 4GB of RAM I run two linux VMs quite easily, so I'm sure that with 8GB and a 4-8 core computer you could handle a more heavyweight windows client as well.

Comment: Yeah, for the RAM thing, i know... screw Apple. I got to Other World Computing for RAM. Thanks for the info on Quad being enough for that. Useful!